# Как согласовывается сочетание «несколько цепей» с глаголом?

Tags: согласование, сказуемые

> С купола потолка свисают /свисает несколько цепей (или ламп).

Как должен употребляться глагол: в единственном числе или во множественном? 
Какому правилу подчиняется это согласование и зависит ли это от порядка слов, прямого или обратного (подлежащее+сказуемое или сказуемое+подлежащее).
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Возможные варианты:

1) **С купола потолка свисает несколько цепей (или ламп).** Грамматическое согласование в ед. числе.

Пассивное состояние, совокупность предметов, сказуемое на первом месте.

2)  **Несколько цепей (или ламп) свисают с купола потолка.** При изменении порядка слов возможно мн. число (согласование по смыслу).

Розенталь:
[§184. Сказуемое при подлежащем – количественно-именном сочетании (счетном обороте)](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_02)

При наличии в количественно-именном сочетании слова **несколько** возможна постановка сказуемого как в форме единственного, так и в форме множественного числа. Например:
а)      За оградой стояло несколько саней... (Пушкин); Несколько человек оглянулось... (Горький); 
б)      Несколько дам скорыми шагами ходили взад и вперед по площадке... (Лермонтов); 
Различное согласование однородных сказуемых в одном и том же предложении в зависимости от того, **обозначают они активное действие или пассивное состояние, совместное или раздельное действие.**

Comment: Ссылка не работает, так и не узнаю, что к чему.

Comment: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_02