# "Несколько... напало и выкинули" - как быть с согласованием?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> На машину туристов напало несколько молодых ребят и, угрожая оружием,
>   выкинули пассажиров, предварительно ограбив.

Может, напал*и*?

Comment: Что за категория — молодые ребята?

Comment: Безусловно, напали, а то согласования не получается.

Comment: Авторское. Тут же нет ошибки. Вопрос нравится - не нравится.

Comment: Ну вот: посмотрите, что все говорят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

напали, потому что:

Постановка сказуемого во множественном числе предпочтительна при наличии следующих условий:

•4)      если при подлежащем имеются однородные сказуемые, например: Большинство заочников своевременно выполнили все контрольные работы, успешно сдали зачеты и хорошо подготовились к экзаменам.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно был похожий вопрос: [**Как согласовывается сочетание «несколько цепей» с глаголом?**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434693/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Я бы написала так:
*На машину туристов **напали** несколько молодых ребят и, угрожая оружием, **выкинули** пассажиров, предварительно ограбив.*
Или:
*Несколько молодых ребят напали на машину туристов и, угрожая оружием, выкинули пассажиров, предварительно ограбив.*

Answer (score 1):

Возможны два варианта исправления:

а) (напрашивающееся) согласовать глагол со вторым действием нападающих, "одушевив" многочисленное напавшее отребье употреблением множественного числа глагола, и

б) сохранить акцент на количестве участников нашествия (согласование с числительным), повторно сославшись на напавших местоимением или существительным (они, напавшие) для описания их второго действия - уже без "и", в оригинале приделывающего второе сказуемое к одинственному подлежащему:

> На машину туристов напало несколько (десятков, сотен) молодых ребят; угрожая оружием,
>   напавшие (они) выкинули пассажиров, предварительно ограбив их.

(вариант "а" нежелателен при больших количествах, напр. очевидно, что "несколько десятков пчёл напал**и**" излишне персонифицирует хаотично воспринимаемое в первый момент зло)